# writing bootloader assembly code on i386 arch, failing to output to terminal correctly

Tags: assembly, x86

this is my first time actually posting a question. I apologize if there are some formats/customs I'm not adhering to, please let me know if that is the case.

I'm in an Intro to OS class, and we're supposed to be writing a bootloader. One part of the assignment is to use INT 0x10 interrupts to output a number to the terminal. For example, I want to print the number of bytes represented by the hex number 0xFFF in some register to its decimal equivalent of 4095. First, I wrote assembly to just output a stored value to its decimal equivalent:

```
.globl main
.code16

main:
    movw $0x9000, %ax
    movw %ax, %ss
    xorw %sp, %sp

    movw $0x0003, %ax
    int $0x10

    movw $0, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es

    mov $0xfff, %eax        # test value, decimal rep is 4095

    mov $0, %bl

    call div10

div10:

    mov $10, %ecx           # divisor
    mov $0, %edx            # set register to 0 - will store remainder
    div %ecx

    push %eax               # push result to stack
    mov %dl, %al            # move remainder value to %al for output
    add $0x30, %al          # add '0' to value to attain ascii equiv
    mov $0x0E, %ah
    int $0x10               # INT 0x10 instruction to print to terminal
    pop %eax                # pop test value back to eax reg

    cmp $0, %eax            # if eax is 0, conversion is complete
    je return

    call div10

return:
```

The output for this block of code is `5904`, which makes sense considering I'm outputting in reverse order. I tried to output in the correct order by pushing the digits to the stack, and popping off accordingly with a counter:

```
.globl main
.code16

main:
    movw $0x9000, %ax
    movw %ax, %ss
    xorw %sp, %sp

    movw $0x0003, %ax
    int $0x10

    movw $0, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es

    mov $0xfff, %eax # test value

    mov $0, %bl

    call div10

div10:

    mov $10, %ecx           # divisor
    mov $0, %edx            # set register to 0 - will store remainder
    div %ecx

    push %dx                # push digit onto stack
    add $1, %bl             # counter for number of digits - inc by 1

    cmp $0, %eax            # if eax is 0, conversion is complete
    je print_bytes

    call div10

print_bytes:

    sub $1, %bl      # counter decremented till 0
    mov $0, %ecx     # set registers to 0
    mov $0, %eax
    pop %cx          # pop digit value to %cx register
    mov %cl, %al     # move to %al to be output

    add $0x30, %al   # add '0' char to convert to ascii equivalent
    mov $0x0E, %ah
    int $0x10        # interrupt to print to screen

    cmp $0, %bl
    je return
    call print_bytes

return:
```

For the given test value (0xFFF, which converts to 4095 decimal), it outputs '4ééé'. It seems to output the first digit correctly, then fails to correctly output the remaining digits. What am I doing wrong? I feel like something is going on when popping my values.

I'm only now learning assembly (usually work with higher-level languages like Java, C++), so I'm sure there are coding practices that are questionable. Please point these out to me! I appreciate any/all feedback.

EDIT: Fixed the issue. @Jester's suggestion not to use `call div10` seems to have resolved the problem. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Use a debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. PS: under what kind of mathematics is `0xFFF=254`? That's `4095`. Also the test value you use seems to be `0xff` which is `255` and doesn't resemble `4ééé` at all.

Comment: The primary problem is that you `call div10` instead of `jmp div10` before `print_bytes`. Or just reverse the `je print_bytes` into `jne div10`. Also it would be a good idea to return from functions...

Comment: Sorry for the errors, I was using different values while writing this just to see what happens and I might've mixed up my code when transferring to SO. I've fixed the errors now; it's now reflective of my actual output.

Thanks for that input; what are the distinctions between using "call" and "jmp"?

Comment: @Jester Changed `call div10` to `jmp div10`, and that seems to have fixed the problem...I'll be looking more into the docs for the differences into call and jmp, and why that might've caused an issue. I appreciate your response.

Comment: `call` is a function call, `jmp` is a "goto". `call` places a return address on the stack, which is what messed up your data.

Comment: Oh i see...is this why you can return from a `call` function? ...Thanks for the explanation. Assembly code is making me lose my hair.

Comment: Yes, the `ret` takes the next item from the stack and uses that for returning.